# Удалить чат с ботом telebot python

Tags: python, telebot

```
if message.text == 'Удалить':
    pass
```

Как сделать чтоб по кнопке удалился весь чат с ботом

Comment: В целом легкого способа нет. Разве что вы будете в бд держать чат_айди и месседж_айди всех сообщений, а потом циклом пройтись и удалить их через `bot.delete_message(chat_id, message_id)`

Comment: присоединяюсь к ответу выше - сообщения хранятся на стороне телеги, те алгоритмически удалить их из любого места в чате не выйдет. можно хранить историю всего чата, айдишники сообщений, но это очень плохой вариант